# Padding ignored when producing vertical overflow?

Tags: html, css, overflow, padding

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmvkzdgn/) to demonstrate.

Resize the window to force a scrollbar when the table can no longer shrink - several problems occur;

1. Window cuts into bottom padding of `<main>` without showing scrollbar.
2. Scrollbar first appears when cutting into table content (purple).
3. `<body>` (yellow) comes short when scrolling - showing `<html>` (green).

**The desired effect is a table that will be as big as possible (height-wise).**

Setting `min-width:100%` in `<body>` seems to make it not come short when scrolling - although I cannot seem to set its children to span the entire height.

Comment: @AndersKink Not sure how width is relevant - also you linked to the same fiddle as I did?

Comment: sorry misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `body` to `min-height: 100vh;` rather than `height: 100%;`. You're forcing a fixed height even when the body has more contents than it can display.

[JSFiddle showing the fix.](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lyfb3hw/3/)

Edit: If you want the `main` to take up 100% of the viewport though, you'll need to set `main` to have `min-height: 100vh;`

Edit2: To make the `table` element fill the `main` element, the only way I can see is to use a "magic number" which assumes that your padding in the `main` object won't change.

```
table {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 32px);  /* magic number, double the padding of `main` */
}
```

Comment: The problem still remains; resizing beyond the tables shrink-capacity and then scrolling - shows the green `<html>`

Comment: Apologies, a last minute tweak there broke it. Have fixed the setup (note body to use `min-height: 100vh;`. [JSFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lyfb3hw/2/)

Comment: The problems are now fixed, although the main functionality is gone. The table no longer takes up 100% of the height when possible.

Comment: Gotcha. The issue here is that we can't make a child element 100% of its parents height unless `height` is set. `min-height` gets ignored. Normally I'd advise using flexbox and `align-items: stretch;` but that doesn't work on `<table>` child elements. In this case if you're certain that the `main` section padding will stay the same, you can use a magic number: `table { min-height: calc(100vh - 32px); }`. [Updated JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lyfb3hw/3/)